# Take next date in utc format in data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to get the current date in Azure Data Factory pipeline and do the following:

- convert it from UTC to GMT time
- add one day
- and make the time component all zero

Sample date (the output from `utcNow()`):

```
2021-06-30T13:00:37.7730202Z
```

Expected Results:

```
2021-07-01T00:00:00Z
```

I have tried the expression `@concat('"', formatDateTime(addToTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(), 'UTC', 'GMT Standard Time'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 1, 'Day'), 'T00:00:00Z', '"')` but it errors.

Comment: Have you looked at [utcNow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#utcnow)?

Comment: I have tried this but not working.

@concat('"', formatDateTime(addToTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(), 'UTC', 'GMT Standard Time'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 1, 'Day'), 'T00:00:00Z', '"')

Comment: Yes I now how to mark the answer.I have done it before as well

Comment: Yes almost same but my expected result  is "2021-07-01T00:00:00Z"

Date should be in double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the Azure Data Factory date functions come with a format switch which you can use to set the format.  The standard format returned by these functions is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), or the format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fffffffK`.  You can over-ride any part of the date format string by writing `0`, `yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00K`.  A simple example which includes `addDays`:

```
@formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(addDays(utcnow(),1), 'UTC', 'GMT Standard Time'), 'yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00K')
```

My results:

[image: Results]

If you do need to wrap the dates in double-quotes, you can use `concat` to add them, but I suggest you do that elsewhere in the pipeline:

```
@concat('"', formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(addDays(utcnow(),1), 'UTC', 'GMT Standard Time'), 'yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00K'), '"')
```